# Shortened ACES Tonemap

Tags: javascript, three.js, glsl

> Will my modified ACES Tonemap work the same as the original one?

Yeah… right… I know I can just look for the differences on my own… "How I wish?" sorry but can't do.

As an amateur, I can't tell the differences with the original ACES and the ACES that I've modified (more like the short version of it).

```
vec3 tMACES(vec3 sample) {
    sample = mat3(0.59719, 0.076, 0.0284, 0.35458, 0.90834, 0.13383, 0.04823, 0.01566, 0.83777) * sample;
    sample = (sample * (sample + 0.0245786) - 0.000090537) / (sample * (0.983729 * sample + 0.432951) + 0.238081);
    return mat3(1.60475, -0.10208, -0.00327, -0.53108, 1.10813, -0.07276, -0.07367, -0.00605, 1.07602) * sample;
}
```

Wondering what the original looks like?

```
// source: https://github.com/selfshadow/ltc_code/blob/master/webgl/shaders/ltc/ltc_blit.fs
vec3 RRTAndODTFit( vec3 v ) {

    vec3 a = v * ( v + 0.0245786 ) - 0.000090537;
    vec3 b = v * ( 0.983729 * v + 0.4329510 ) + 0.238081;
    return a / b;

}

// this implementation of ACES is modified to accommodate a brighter viewing environment.
// the scale factor of 1/0.6 is subjective. see discussion in #19621.

vec3 ACESFilmicToneMapping( vec3 color ) {

    // sRGB => XYZ => D65_2_D60 => AP1 => RRT_SAT
    const mat3 ACESInputMat = mat3(
        vec3( 0.59719, 0.07600, 0.02840 ), // transposed from source
        vec3( 0.35458, 0.90834, 0.13383 ),
        vec3( 0.04823, 0.01566, 0.83777 )
    );

    // ODT_SAT => XYZ => D60_2_D65 => sRGB
    const mat3 ACESOutputMat = mat3(
        vec3(  1.60475, -0.10208, -0.00327 ), // transposed from source
        vec3( -0.53108,  1.10813, -0.07276 ),
        vec3( -0.07367, -0.00605,  1.07602 )
    );

    color *= toneMappingExposure / 0.6;

    color = ACESInputMat * color;

    // Apply RRT and ODT
    color = RRTAndODTFit( color );

    color = ACESOutputMat * color;

    // Clamp to [0, 1]
    return saturate( color );

}
```

[Don't trust the code above? Click here then.](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/dev/src/renderers/shaders/ShaderChunk/tonemapping_pars_fragment.glsl.js)
Helpful tips is much appreciated.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You inlined the function and the matrices, and left out the exposure adjustment; not surprising that it's (almost) identical; but what's the point?

Comment: @YakovGalka Well… that explains it all for me, thanks!